# mongoose query same field with different values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Is there a way to user `mongoose.find({title:'some title'})` to query the same field with multiple values? For example something like this  `mongoose.find({title:'some title', title:'some other title'})` sends back only documents matching `title:'some other title` is there a way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 88):

You should use the MongoDB [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator -

```
mongoose.find({title: {$in: ['some title', 'some other title']}})
```

You provide an array to `$in` operator and it will return all the documents which have an exact title in the array specified.

Comment: It's a correct solution, don't know why didn't he accept this.

Comment: the field should be array to use $in operator, this question was for field type string/text

Answer (score 8):

Found this in 2021 with the same question. It seems the $in operator is no longer necessary. As long as you pass find() an array of items, it will search for all of them.

Ex:

```
Furniture.find({
  room: [ 'first_id', 'second_id' ]
})
```

This will return the documents where room is the first OR second id.

Can be written in a query string like:

```
?room=first_id&room=second_id
```

There's no parsing needed—Node parses this into an array automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you're building this off a URL query eg: `http://url.com/posts?title=one` but with multiple values in the query here's an approach:

Use a separator like `&` in your query like so `http://url.com/posts?title=title&other%20title`

Then setup your request function to operate with async:

eg. `async function listPosts() {}`

Then use the `&` seperator to detect if it's a query for multiple items or not and set your query accordingly. So the whole query for a list post would look something like this:

```
async function listPosts(req, res, next) {
  const urlParts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  const { query } = urlParts;
  // Check if URL query has & char and split into multiple query strings
  const multiQuery = async () => {
    // Return array of any query param values containing '&'
    const mQueryArr = Object.values(query).filter(i => i.indexOf('&') > -1);
    if (mQueryArr.length) {
      Object.keys(query).forEach((key) => {
        if (query[key].indexOf('&') > -1) {
          // Split strings containing '&' and set query to search multiple using
          // mongooses '$in' operator
          const queries = query[key].split('&');
          query[key] = { $in: queries };
        }
      });
    }
  };
  await multiQuery();
  Post.find(query)
    .exec((err, posts) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.json({ posts });
    });
}
```

Hope this helps someone as it took me a while to figure out the approach for a URL query with multiple queries for the same object key.

Answer (score 0):

The mongodb text search {"title":"some thing"} will return any document that has the word "some", or the word "thing" in it. I won't do an exact match to the phrase "some thing".

Therefore, if you wanted to find all titles that contained any series of words, you would just do {"title":"word one two three four something dog cat last word"} and it would return any document that has any of those words in it.

If you want to do exact phrase matching, then you would have to change your original query.

Comment: *The mongodb query {"title":"some thing"} will return any document that has the word "some", or the word "thing" in it*. Are you sure about that?

Comment: text search takes "A string of terms that MongoDB parses and uses to query the text index. MongoDB performs a logical OR search of the terms unless specified as a phrase. See Behavior for more information on the field." https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/.  Unless mongoose modifies this behavior, I would expect it to be the same.

Comment: I agree but no where in your answer you mentioned **text search**. The OP was talking about the find search and your answer seemed misleading.

Comment: Updated my answer to avoid any confusion.