# how to write Mongoose find filter with 2 values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to write a mongoose Find() filter where it should return the result of users whos  name are either "Ram" or "Shyam"

find({ name: "Ram" or "Shyam"});

How do I write it in a way that it pull all the users that has name set as Ram or Shyam

Comment: Found one more way
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146716/mongoose-query-same-field-with-different-values

Answer (score 1):

Here the query you're looking for:

```
Collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      name: "Ram"
    },
    {
      name: "Shyam"
    }
  ]
})
```

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/