# Node.js: Render mongoose elements based on conditions

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

Basically, I'm trying to make an e-commerce kind of a website, with categories for male and female and subcategories. My aim is to render mongoose elements based on their categories on one page using ejs templates.

**app.js:**

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/journalDB', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});





const journalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  category: String,
  subcategory: String,
  rating: Number,
  link: String,
  description: String,
});


const Journal = mongoose.model("Journal", journalSchema);



app.get("/", function(req, res){


Journal.find({}, function(err, journals){

  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }



    else{

    res.render("home", {journals: journals});
    }
});


});




app.get("/category", function(req, res){
  Journal.find({$or:[{category: "Woman"},{category: "Man"}]}, function(err, journals){

    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }

      else {
      res.render("category", {
        journals: journals
      });




    }
    });
});

app.get("/favourite", function(req, res){
  res.render("favourite");
});

app.get("/man", function(req, res){
  res.render("man");
});


app.get("/woman", function(req, res){

  res.render("woman");
});

app.get("/other", function(req, res){
  res.render("other");
});

app.get("/compose", function(req, res){
  res.render("compose");
});




app.post("/compose", function(req, res){

  const journal = new Journal({
    title: req.body.journalTitle,
    category: req.body.journalCategory,
    subcategory: req.body.journalSubcategory,
    link: req.body.journalLink,
    description: req.body.journalDescription
  });


  journal.save(function(err){
    if(!err){
      res.redirect("/");
    }
    else{
      console.log(err);
    }
  });


});



app.get("/journals/:journalId", function(req, res){


  const requestedJournalId = req.params.journalId;

  Journal.findOne({_id: requestedJournalId}, function(err, foundJournal){
      res.render("stats", {
        title: foundJournal.title,
        subcategory: foundJournal.subcategory,
        link: foundJournal.link,
        description: foundJournal.description
      });
  });


});





app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

**category.ejs:**

```
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>

<div class="container py-4 new-offers">




          <a href="/woman" class="text-color"><h2 class="custom-heading">Women</h2></a>
          <div class="row">







            <% journals.forEach(function(journal){ %>


            <div class="col-md-4 col-6 target" >
              <a href="/journals/<%=journal._id%>">
              <div class="flex-container">
                    <div class="card-icon p-3">
                      <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content p-3">
                      <% if(journal.category.toLowerCase() == "woman"){ %>
                        <h6><%=journal.category%></h6>
                        <p><%=journal.subcategory%></p>

                        <%}%>



                    </div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>


            <% }) %>


            <button type="button" name="button" class="btn woman"><h5>Show More</h5></button>




          </div>

        </div>



<div class="container py-4 special-offers">

            <a href="/man" class="text-color"><h2 class="custom-heading">Men</h2></a>
            <div class="row">


              <% journals.forEach(function(journal){ %>


              <div class="col-md-4 col-6 target" >
                <div class="flex-container">
                      <div class="card-icon p-3">
                        <a  href="/journals/<%=journal._id%>"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag fa-3x"></i></a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-content p-3">
                        <% if(journal.category.toLowerCase() == "man"){ %>
                          <h6><%=journal.category%></h6>
                          <p><%=journal.subcategory%></p>
                       <%}%>




                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <% }) %>




              <button type="button" name="button" class="btn man"><h5>Show More</h5></button>
            </div>



          </div>

<script>

  $(function(){
    $(".target").slice(0, 6).show()
    $(".woman").on("click",function(){
      $(".target:hidden").slice(0, 3).slideDown()
      if($(".target:hidden").length == 0) {
        $(".woman").fadeout('slow');
      }
    });

});
</script>



<%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

But what i get is this:
[image]

As you can see from the picture, all items in the database get rendered on the page, even though if statement in the ejs file specify which elements should be displayed.
My main goal is to get rid of these empty cards and display only those elements that satisfy the condition in the if statement.
I'm new to node.js and mongoose, I haven't been able to find the solution from similar questions on stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was misplaced if statement in ejs file, instead of wrapping only heading and paragraph tags, the whole div(in this case with a class of target) should be inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I’m having trouble understanding your question. I think you’re asking how to find elements that have the category man or woman, if is that what your are searching for you can try ot change this :

---

```
Journal.find({$or:[{category: "Woman"},{category: "Man"}]}
```

By this line :

---

```
Journal.find({ category: [ 'Woman', 'Man' ] })
```

In your case you are searching for the same field with multiple values.
Try to read this also: [mongoose query same field with different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146716/mongoose-query-same-field-with-different-values)
I hope that this will help you

Comment: I understand how to find them, the issue is in ejs file. I wanted these empty cards on screenshots not to get displayed. Anyway, I figured it out, turns out I just put the if statement to check the category in the wrong place in the category.ejs.